# How to communicate between services in Kubernetes in a secure way

Tags: api, kubernetes, microservices

I have a few node.js microservices running in Kubernetes and now I would need to  find a way to communicate between them. I was thinking to expose an endpoint that would only be accessible internally from other pods. I have been searching for hours, but didn't find a solution that would be secure enough. Is there a way to make it work as such? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If you want your service to be accessible only from selected pods - you may use [Network Policies](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/). They allow to define what pods can talk to what pods on the network level. For example, you may expose your service through ingress and allow only ingress controller to talk to your application. That way you can be sure that your application can only be available through ingress (with authentication) and no other way.

Network Policies are supported only be some network plugins:

- Calico
- Open vSwitch
- Cilium
- Weave
- Romana

Answer (score 2):

> communicate between services in Kubernetes in a secure way

Natively, Kubernetes does not provide mutual TLS solution to the services for  encrypted communication, that's where Istio with [mutual-tls-authenticatione](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/security/#mutual-tls-authentication) bring this functionality to the platform.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use 'cluster ip' as service type. this would keep your services exposed within cluster.  you can use services by their name over Http.

for any service that is talking publicly you may need to use load balancer service type or ingress controller.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve this:

1. Encryption, which at least needs some kind of certificate management. You could also use a service-mesh for encryption but this needs some efford.
2. Autorisation via Access-Tokens.
3. Securing the Kubernetes cluster and the ingress.
4. Network filtering (firewall).

This list is far from complete.

Note that doing just item 2 will not solve your problem. I think you will at least need  items 1 and 2 to get some level of security.